# can not open download folder mac os sierra

Tags: macos, dock, folders, bug

when I drag and drop files from my dock download folder it crashes randomly.  When I try to open the folder it does not respond or there comes a empty blank folder.

Sometimes the dock is crashing and I am not able to click on any icons.

Here is a video about it, who can help me to solve this iritating problem? After a restart it fixes itself but it comes back.

https://youtu.be/ZG5Zg-co5JU

Comment: How many files do you have in your download folder - fx if you open it in Finder? If you've got many videos or other files that renders icons based on file contents, your computer may have a hard time showing them.

Comment: Yes I have a lot of video's inside. I want to use list view, but then I can not drag and drop the files.

Comment: It happens also with almost no files in it. I had only 1 jpg.

Comment: Can you open Terminal, run `cd ~/Downloads && ls -al .` and *paste* the output into your question?

Comment: Did you see anything suspicious in Activity Monitor with high CPU usage?

Comment: This happens to me, too. I only have a couple small files in there. It's not related to the folder's contents.